# Time complexity a recursive function

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

> Suppose given recurrence relation
>
> $$T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+T(n-\sqrt{n})+n$$  $$T(1)=O(1)$$
>
> How we can find an order of above recurrence relation?

My attempt:

I read following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195721/solve-the-recurrence-relation-tn-tn-sqrt-mathstrut-n-t-sqrt-mat), but get stuck in understanding that solution.

Comment: It would be more helpful to tell us what parts you understand and what was the first part you were stuck on.  Otherwise, it's hard to know how to tailor the answer, without just answering again.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the formula to find a pattern:

$$
T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + T(n-\sqrt{n}) + n = T(n^{\frac{1}{4}}) +‌ T(\sqrt{n} - n^{\frac{1}{4}}) + T(\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}) + T(n-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}) + 2n
$$

As you can see, in each expansion, the sum of values inside the functions is $n$. Hence, you can show using the mathematical induction that each time one factor of $n$ is added to the non-recursive part. Hence the only thing is showing that what is the height of this tree of expansion.

As the bigger term is $n - \sqrt{n}$, we should find how long it takes to reach to a constant value. As each time a constant factor of $\sqrt{n}$ is subtracted from $n$ (see from expansion), $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$-times recursions are required to reach to a constant value.

Therefore, $T(n) = \Theta(n\sqrt{n})$.